# Strange alpha blending with UIImageView on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

Currently I'm working on a simple image editor where you can with a brush alter the alpha channel.

My problem is, when a UIImageView with 0 or near zero alpha image is presented on another UIView, that has a dark color (like brown, black, etc), a strange composition appears. Image becomes visible like its alpha has never been changed. When the back UIView is white, everything is normal.

You'll want to say "keep it white" but I'm currently using this UIView as the background canvas and user has the ability to change the color.

The captures I took are from Reveal, but the appearance is exactly the same on device as well. Here is what I mean with all this talk:

This is an image with 20% alpha set to all it's pixels. The image looks ok. From Reveal, I can see that the image has the correct alpha channel. Everyting is as it should be.

[image: Image with alpha 20%]

Here is the same image with 15% alpha on a darker blue background (sorry, while capturing I changed the alpha). From Reveal, everything is again looking normal.

[image: Background color changed]

But when you look at the device, this is what you see. This is the same UIImage with 15% alpha set to all pixels and presented in UIImageView.

[image: What is going on here?]

The image is fully appearing on the background dark blue UIView, like its alpha is not 15%. Changing alpha when working on a dark background has not much effect. It simply adds blue all over, or 100% alpha returns to the original image. Even when setting the alpha of all pixels to 0, the image is clearly visible.

Is there something I'm missing? Why this composition (or blending of two UIView objects) error/bug/problem appearing? Is there a value that I am forgetting to set? Or is this normal and am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and also looking for an answer. It's odd.

Comment: Hmm, I figured it out! At least for me, the problem was passing colors to UIColor in the range 0-255 instead of 0-1. All components have to be divided by 255! Otherwise, you run into strange issues like this. It's interesting to know if you ever want to color everything.